# Why do I get `undefined` when reading state variables set via `useState()`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I made a Smart Contract (variable `rps`), which fires two events:

- `P1Commits` (refers to a newly created game, returning its unique `id`, along with other stuff)
- `P2Joins` (refers to a previously existing game, returning its unique `id`, along with other stuff)

Now, I'm making a React app which listens to these events (via this: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.4.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id50), and updates a webpage.

My React App should display two types of games:

- Open Games (stored in the `openGames` state variable)
- User Active Games (stored in the `userActiveGames` state variable)

How `rps` events should affect state:

1. When `P1Commits` is fired, a new game object should be added to `openGames` (already working)
2. When `P2Joins` is fired, the relevant game should be:

   1. Read from `openGames`
   2. Updated with the info in `P2Joins`
   3. Removed from `openGames`
   4. Added to `userActiveGames`

But when I try to perform `2.1` (reading `openGames` into `tempGames`), I get `undefined`.

But why?

My code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import web3 from "./web3";
import rps from "./rps";

const App = () => {
  const [ account, setAccount ] = useState("");
  const [ owner, setOwner ] = useState("");
  const [ openGames, setOpenGames ] = useState({});
  const [ userActiveGames, setUserActiveGames ] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    web3.eth.getAccounts().then(accounts => setAccount(accounts[0]));
    rps.methods.owner().call().then(address => setOwner(address));

    rps.events.P1Commits()
      .on('data', event => {
        const values = event.returnValues;
        const newGame = {"bet": values.bet, "over": false, "p1": values.p1, "p1Commit": values.p1Commit, "p2": null, "p2Choice": null, "p2ChoiceTime": null};
        setOpenGames(prevState => ({...prevState, [values.id]: newGame}));
      })

    rps.events.P2Joins({
      filter: {
        id: Object.keys(openGames).filter(key => openGames[key].p1 === account), // ids of open games with user as player 1
        p2: account // player 2 joining is user
    }})
      .on('data', event => {
        const values = event.returnValues;
        const tempGames = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(openGames)); // copy without reference
        const joinedGame = tempGames[values.id]; // why is joinedGame undefined?
        [joinedGame.p2, joinedGame.p2Choice, joinedGame.p2ChoiceTime] = [values.p2, values.p2Choice, values.p2ChoiceTime];
        //setOpenGames(prevState => ({...prevState, [values.id]: newGame})); // need to change this to remove games from open games
        setUserActiveGames(prevState => ({...prevState, [values.id]: joinedGame}));
      })

  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <p>Contract Owner: {owner}</p>
        <p>User Account: {account}</p>

        <div>
          <h3>{Object.keys(openGames).length} Open Games:</h3>
          <ul>
            {Object.entries(openGames).map(([k, v], i) => <li key={k}>{JSON.stringify(k)}: {JSON.stringify(v)}</li>)}
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div>
          <h3>{Object.keys(userActiveGames).length} User Active Games:</h3>
          <ul>
            {Object.entries(userActiveGames).map(([k, v], i) => <li key={k}>{JSON.stringify(k)}: {JSON.stringify(v)}</li>)}
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. I believe you are doing too much in your useEffect, split it out and do 1 thing per useEffect
2. check your promise statements in your useEffect, you may need a `catch` statement.
3. you are setting `account` early in the useEffect, then comparing it against another value later on, this is not going to work the way you think it will, hence you need to split up your useEffects.

My guess is accounts[0] is undefined, and you are setting state waaaay to much in that one hook.